# Excel String Concatenation Question

Tags: excel

For example, I have

40572 in A1. However, it is set to "Date", so what I see is actually 1/29/2011
888 in B1. Nothing fancy.

=A1&B1 in another cell. It shows 40572888.

However, what I want to see is 1/29/2011888 while still having 40572888 in the values. So that the first 5 digits are viewed as "Date" and the rest as "General". I don't want to use "=TEXT" because it doesn't preserve the value 40572.  Is this possible?

Comment: Formatting is by cell in Excel; one cell cannot include both date-formatted and general-formatted values.  Since you are concatenating these values, the contents of the cell will be treated as text no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try via `CONCATENATE`

Example:

```
A1 = 1/29/2011
B1 = 888 
C1 = CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1, "MM/DD/YYYY"), " ", B1)
```

Please try on your own, because my excel is only available in german ;)

Btw: what do you mean with

> it doesn't preserve the value 40572

Comment: You need to use commas instead of ";". Should be "=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1, "MM/DD/YYYY"), " ", B1) or take out the second part if you don't want to space seperator between the two.